# My raycast is not activating my enemies death in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting, ragdoll

I've been trying to make my enemy fall when it's health reaches zero.
So I made a damage variable. The damage will subtract to the health and when it reaches zero or lower, he's supposed to turn into a ragdoll. But its seems as he's not dying in the first place..

In the gun script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera Cam;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Fire();
        }
        
        void Fire()
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(Cam.transform.position, Cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
                
                Enemy enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
                if (enemy != null)
                {
                    enemy.damage(damage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the enemy script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator myAnim;

    List<Rigidbody> ragdollRigids;



    public float health = 100f;
    public void damage (float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        activateRagdoll();
    }

    //Update

    void Start()
    {
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        ragdollRigids = new List<Rigidbody>(transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>());
        ragdollRigids.Remove(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        DeactivateRagdoll();
       
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    //Ragdoll dependencies.

    public void activateRagdoll()
    {
        myAnim.enabled = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ragdollRigids.Count; i++)
        {
            ragdollRigids[i].useGravity = true;
            ragdollRigids[i].isKinematic = false;
        }
    }

    public void DeactivateRagdoll()
    {
        myAnim.enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ragdollRigids.Count; i++)
        {
            ragdollRigids[i].useGravity = false;
            ragdollRigids[i].isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220259/discussion-on-question-by-freddie-silver-my-raycast-is-not-activating-my-enemies).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Your variables (`damage` and `amount`) are named differently but are used for the same purpose. I have edited your code. There *should* be no errors. If there are, contact me my commenting on my answer.

### Code

**Gun:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera Cam;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Fire();
        }
        
        void Fire()
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(Cam.transform.position, Cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
                
                Enemy enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
                if (enemy != null)
                {
                    enemy.damage(damage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Enemy:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator myAnim;

    List<Rigidbody> ragdollRigids;



    public float health = 100f;
    public void damage (float damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        activateRagdoll();
    }

    //Update

    void Start()
    {
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        ragdollRigids = new List<Rigidbody>(transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>());
        ragdollRigids.Remove(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        DeactivateRagdoll();
       
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    //Ragdoll dependencies.

    public void activateRagdoll()
    {
        myAnim.enabled = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ragdollRigids.Count; i++)
        {
            ragdollRigids[i].useGravity = true;
            ragdollRigids[i].isKinematic = false;
        }
    }

    public void DeactivateRagdoll()
    {
        myAnim.enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ragdollRigids.Count; i++)
        {
            ragdollRigids[i].useGravity = false;
            ragdollRigids[i].isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this work? If it did, please accept my answer so I can know that it worked - and it also help the community! Win-win. If it does not work, tell me by commenting so that I can help you further.

Comment: @GUESTAS Thank you, it said that this: The name 'amount' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I will edit the code/answer I have. Try using the new code. Contact me if there are still any errors. No errors? - accept.

Comment: Oh no That did not work,i'm afraid. Maybe its to do with where I assigned the enemy script? I assigned it to the swat prefab,but then it has: swat > geo and then the ragdoll pieces. But the thing is I cant assign the animator to the "geo".

Comment: I could try, but then that would remove the effect I wanted... Should I try it?

Comment: Try it, but if it works, at least you know what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: And keep a backup of the project in case it does not work

Comment: Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

Comment: Does the above line hit?